# Derivatives with rational orders like y^(1,5)'

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Is there any mathematical definiton of rational derivatives?

We all know y,y'',y''',...,y^(n) are orders of discrete numbers. Is there anything like one and a half 1,5th derivative of a function?

Firstly it may sound not consistent with definiton of derivatives. However it could make sense since we can calculate exponents of a number say 3^1, 3^2 and 3^(1,5) with continious exponents.

I have tried to google it, but all the results were about derivatives of rational functions.

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus could be of interest.

Comment: In fact the concept was already considered by Lebiniz.